# It is not printing from Child Class

Tags: python

There is super class with the name Employee has the following fields.
empNum, name, address and DOB.
There are two child class or sub class of Employee class. They are FullTimeEmployee and PartTimeEmployee.
FullTimeEmployee has monthlySalary (other than the fields in Super Class)
PartiTime Employee has hourlyRate (other than the fields in Super Class)

Here is a code that i have written in Python.

However when i print it is only printing the fields in the superclass.

May i know which part im doing wrong.

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        if 'empNum' in kwargs:self._empNum=kwargs['empNum']
        if 'name' in kwargs:self._name=kwargs['name']
        if 'address' in kwargs:self._address=kwargs['address']
        if 'dob' in kwargs:self._dob=kwargs['dob']
        
    def empNum(self,en=None):
        if en:self._empNum=en
        return self._empNum
    
    def name(self,nme=None):
        if nme:self._name=nme
        return self._name
    
    def address(self,addr=None):
        if addr:self._address=addr
        return self._address
    
    def dob(self,db=None):
        if db:self._dob=db
        return self._name
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self._empNum +","+ self._name+","+self._dob+","+self._address

#child class
class FullTimeEmployee(Employee):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__( **kwargs)
        if 'monthlySalary' in kwargs:self._monthlySalary=kwargs['monthlySalary']

  
            
    def monthlySalary(self, s=None):
        if s:self._monthlySalary=s
        return self._monthlySalary
    
    def _str_(self):
        return super().__init__ + "," + self._monthlySalary
    
 #child class   
class PartTimeEmployee(Employee):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__( **kwargs)
        if 'hourlyRate' in kwargs:self._hourlyRate=kwargs['hourlyRate']
        
         
              
    def hourlyRate(self, hr=None):
        if hr:self._hourlyRate=hr
        return self._hourlyRate
    
    def _str_(self):
        return str(super()._str_()) +"," + self._hourlyRate
    
   
                   
def main():
    records = []  
    test = []
    emp = Employee(empNum='100', name="Ibrahim Shathir", address="H. North Pole,Male', Maldives", dob="16-05-1989")
    records.append(emp)
    emp1 = PartTimeEmployee(empNum='101', name="Mohamed Latheef", address="H. North Pole,Male', Maldives", dob="16-05-1989", hourlyRate="150")
    records.append(emp1)
    emp2 = FullTimeEmployee(empNum='102', name="Shujau Ibrahim", address="H. North Pole,Male', Maldives", dob="16-05-1989", monthlySalary="12500")
    records.append(emp2)
    
    print(records[0])
    for emps in records:
          print(emps)
    print(emp2)
    
    

    
if __name__ == '__main__':main() 


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pzph.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbOHv.jpg
```

Comment: Your child classes implement `_str_` (only a single underscore) instead of `__str__`

Comment: Thanks a lot. it helped. i missed the underscore in there

Answer (score 0):

Please override `__str__` instead of `_str_` in subclass. The following code should work.

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        if 'empNum' in kwargs:self._empNum=kwargs['empNum']
        if 'name' in kwargs:self._name=kwargs['name']
        if 'address' in kwargs:self._address=kwargs['address']
        if 'dob' in kwargs:self._dob=kwargs['dob']
        
    def empNum(self,en=None):
        if en:self._empNum=en
        return self._empNum
    
    def name(self,nme=None):
        if nme:self._name=nme
        return self._name
    
    def address(self,addr=None):
        if addr:self._address=addr
        return self._address
    
    def dob(self,db=None):
        if db:self._dob=db
        return self._name
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self._empNum +","+ self._name+","+self._dob+","+self._address

#child class
class FullTimeEmployee(Employee):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__( **kwargs)
        if 'monthlySalary' in kwargs:self._monthlySalary=kwargs['monthlySalary']
   
    def monthlySalary(self, s=None):
        if s:self._monthlySalary=s
        return self._monthlySalary
    
    def __str__(self):
        prefix = super().__str__()
        return '{}, {}'.format(prefix, self._monthlySalary) 
    
 #child class   
class PartTimeEmployee(Employee):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__( **kwargs)
        if 'hourlyRate' in kwargs:self._hourlyRate=kwargs['hourlyRate']
              
    def hourlyRate(self, hr=None):
        if hr:self._hourlyRate=hr
        return self._hourlyRate

    def __str__(self):
        prefix = super().__str__()
        return '{}, {}'.format(prefix, self._hourlyRate) 
                   
def main():
    records = []  
    test = []
    emp = Employee(empNum='100', name="Ibrahim Shathir", address="H. North Pole,Male', Maldives", dob="16-05-1989")
    records.append(emp)
    emp1 = PartTimeEmployee(empNum='101', name="Mohamed Latheef", address="H. North Pole,Male', Maldives", dob="16-05-1989", hourlyRate="150")
    records.append(emp1)
    emp2 = FullTimeEmployee(empNum='102', name="Shujau Ibrahim", address="H. North Pole,Male', Maldives", dob="16-05-1989", monthlySalary="12500")
    records.append(emp2)
    
    print(records[0])
    for emps in records:
          print(emps)
    print(emp2)
     
if __name__ == '__main__':main()
```